# Is it possible to get By object having WebElement

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using @FindBy annotations to locate WebElements. But I want to use these WebElements in methods as parameters. I had success with this only if WebElement was found on page. But if I want to wait for it I must use By (with same locator) instead.

E.g.

```
private static final String SEARCHFIELD_LOC = "#search input[placeholder]";
@FindBy(css = SEARCHFIELD_LOC)
public WebElement searchField;
public By searchField_by = new By.ByCssSelector(SEARCHFIELD_LOC);
```

That way I can use this WebElement as By object in some method, like

```
public boolean isElementDisplayedWithWait(final By by) { .... }
```

So for each element I have 4 lines of code. I'm to lazy and searching for a way to simplify that.

Answer (score 1):

I found totally another solution. I will store my locators as strings.

```
public String searchField = ".slide.slide_search input[placeholder]"
```

So only 1 line of code per locator. And I hope supporting only CSS locators will be enough. I will NOT use @FindBy for getting WebElements. Instead, I will get WebElements using special method that will wait for element and will log what's going on. I will implement getting WebElement like this:

```
WebElement we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(new By.ByCssSelector(locator)));
```

where wait is

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>( driver )
                .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring( StaleElementReferenceException.class ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternate of having wait/assertions/verification methods with webelement itself is available with extended webelement in [QAF formerly ISFW](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/). For example:

```
@FindBy(css = SEARCHFIELD_LOC)
public WebElement searchField;

searchField.waitForPresent();
searchField.assertPresent(); //auto wait
searchField.verifyPresent(); //auto wait
```

Reference:

1. [QAF Selenium testing-frameworks](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/)
2. [ISFW FAQ](http://blog.infostretch.com/isfw-faq)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use any frameworks for now.